# Rolling back a VERY SPECIFIC preview package that led to a dirty project

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

Unfortunately guys, this one needs a bit of context, bear with me.

So, some months ago I was cursed with a gift from Microsoft in the form of an issue with the .net packages needed to publish to Azure. This basically meant that for a few days it was impossible to publish to Azure from visual studio, and if you did try it just took your site down and didn't let you bring it up. Thankfully, I was able to fix that issue thanks to the answer in this post:
[Azure App Services will not start after App Insights upgrade to 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120919/azure-app-services-will-not-start-after-app-insights-upgrade-to-2-5)

However, that fix involved installing a preview package along with a bunch'a dependencies that left me with a dirty project (as I was warned, it was worth the trade off at the time as there was no way of knowing when I would be able to take my site back up).

Now though, I would like to get rid of that package and cleanup my project so I can move up from .net core 2.0 to some of the more useful versions, but everything I have tried to do so far has failed.

Does anyone have any good tips to cleaning up these dirty projects, or, in particular, how the hell I can remove this and all associated packages? 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureKeyVault.HostingStartup --version 2.1.0-preview1-27946

**Things I've tried** that unfortunately didn't help:

- Update Microsoft.NetCore.App to either a previous or current version.
  Stopped by NuGet with the somewhat expected "Implicitly referenced by
  an SDK"
- Download & install latest SDK
- Uninstalling all versions of SDK, download latest & updated Visual Studio.
  Error: project couldn't find the package. Checked Nuget, all `csproj` files and didn't find it.

Worth noting that at this point my project was completely broken as not a single `Microsoft.AspNetCore` dependency would resolve. This was fixed by redownloading the cursed package but now I am just back to square one. Sure my project builds and deploys fine, but I am back to being forced to use `Microsoft.NetCore.App` V2.0.0.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "but everything I have tried to do so far has failed"? What have you tried? This helps us not do suggestions you tried already, and helps you not having to comment "Yeah. Tried that. Didn't work." too often ;)

Comment: Sure, lets see if I remember all as I have been a couple of days on this.
-First thing I tried was to update Microsoft.NetCore.App to either a previous or current version. This was stopped by NuGet with the somewhat expected "Implicitly referenced by an SDK" error.
-Next I tried to download latest SDK and install, but this had no visible effect.
-Tried uninstalling all existing versions of the SDK, download only latest and updated Visual Studio. (This was about the most promising step). 
1/2

Comment: However at this last point is when I started getting the error that the project couldn't find the package listed above but I couldn't find what was referencing it no matter where I looked (admittedly I am not great at looking for this), I checked Nuget, all my csproj files and no mention of it, as well as a "moonshot" attempt to do search for that string in all the project files that would let me search them as text.

2/2

Comment: Worth noting that at this point my project was completely broken as not a single Microsoft.AspNetCore dependency would resolve. This was fixed by redownloading the cursed package but now I am just back to square one. Sure my project builds and deploys fine, but I am back to being forced to use Microsoft.NetCore.App at v 2.0.0

Comment: First, read the [documentaiton](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2#migrate) and understand what implict version means. It allows you to remove most of the packages that are already included in the meta package and **REMOVE** the `Version=xxx` Attribute on the Metapackages `PackageReference`, it will then pickup the latest on your system installed runtime that matches your target platform `netcoreapp2.2` picking latest 2.2.x packages). In order to use newer packages, change the platform (`netcoreapp2.2` either in cs proj or the properties)

Comment: Thanks @Tseng, not quite what the question was about but it is appropriate reading now that I have a project on 2.2 that actually builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the cached output of the projects might be hindering you. Unfortunately, I've had that a few times as well. Clean solution won't help you.

Please try these steps:

1. Clean the solution (Right-click, Clean Solution)
2. Remove *all* references to said package.
3. Close Visual Studio.
4. Open up all `csproj` files in a text editor and set the TargetFramework to `netcoreapp2.2`.
5. Delete *all* `bin` and `obj` folders under all of the projects in the solution.
6. Open up Visual Studio, load the solution, add any packages needed and rebuild.

Because I've encountered issues with the stuff in `bin` and `obj` folders quite frequently, I even created a `cleanme.bat` file to remove all the files in those folders:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S bin') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S obj') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

Comment: Well this worked a treat. I had tried the clean as well as manually setting the TargetFramework but both attempts had been done in isolation and from within Visual Studio. These instructions sorted it all.